# Xcode Account Authentication Failure

Tags: xcode, xcode14

There is a problem when I'm trying to sign in to my Apple ID account. Re-signing in doesn't help.

[image: Screenshot]

Xcode 14.0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @FlorianMetzger-Noel it's a proper question.

Comment: @FedorPashin not according to the stack overflow rules. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am getting the same error. Started in Xcode 14 b6. Removing the account and adding again doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem

That's how I solved it:

1. You have to access the section where the **Xcode accounts** are. To access it you can do it through the `View accounts` button that appears in the warning or through the `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` menu.
2. Once there, **select the account** that appears in the warning and click on the `-` button at the bottom of the dialog.
3. Once the account is removed, in the same section, click on the `+` button and **add that account again** by selecting *Apple ID* account type (it will ask you to log in).
4. **Restart Xcode** to apply the changes (although the warning should be gone by now).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did this multiple times, issue persists in Xcode 14.2 (warning is gone for like 10-15 minutes after doing this, but then it reappears again)

Comment: That's solution didn't work here. Xcode 14.2 and MacOS 12.6.2.

Comment: Either the one mentioned or try developer.apple.com might have some agreements you need to accept. Really not sure why this is happening when there are no agreements pending